# I do not know why this Java Script code not run in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In dropdownlist `onchange` event call `FillSystem()` Ajax Request is sent but `scopeId` selector do not run this below method.

```
function FillSystem() {
    var _scopeId = $('#ScopeId').val();
    var _roleId = $('#Role_Id').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Account/FillSystem',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { scopeId: _scopeId, roleId: _roleId },
        success: function (systems) {
            $("#SystemId").html(""); // clear before appending new list
            $.each(systems, function (i, system) {
                $("#SystemId").append(
                    $('<option></option>').val(system.System_Id).html(system.SystemName));
            });
        }
    });
}
```

```
<table class="table w3-striped w3-border w3-card-4" style="width: 65%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Scope
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("ScopeId", null,"--Please Select--", new { style = "width:250px", @onchange = "FillSystem()" })
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>System</td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("SystemId", null, "--please select--", new { style = "width:250px" })
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: drop the html as well

Comment: plz add view code

Comment: @MohammadAkbari I done

Comment: refraze the PARSED html

Comment: where is the SystemId select ?

Answer (score 0):

you use DropDown in table and probably multiple row exist, and multiple id with same, your $('#ScopeId') selector, select first element with ScopeId.

first remove @onchange = "FillSystem()" from DropDownList, then try this code

```
(function ($) { 
    function FillSystem() {     

        var _scopeId = $(this).val();   
        var _roleId = $('#Role_Id').val();  
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");   

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Account/FillSystem',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { scopeId: _scopeId, roleId: _roleId },
            success: function (systems) {
                $("#SystemId", $row).html(""); // clear before appending new list
                $.each(systems, function (i, system) {
                    $("#SystemId", $row).append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(system.System_Id).html(system.SystemName));
                });
            }
        });
    }

    $(function () { 

        $("table").on("change", "#ScopeId", FillSystem)
    });

}(jQuery));
```